# How can I obtain the details of a Webhook sent to my server?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Good afternoon, colleagues.

I am creating a BOT for my Discord server. Its sole purpose is to "intercept" a message I receive through a Webhook, but I haven't been able to achieve it yet. With my current code, I get the following error:

[image]

This is my current code:

```js
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Partials,
  Collection,
  WebhookClient,
} = require("discord.js");
// const { Webhook } = require("discord-webhook-node");
const config = require("./config");
const webhook = new WebhookClient([config.webhooks.bizDataMr]);
console.clear();

//webhook.fetchMessage()

const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages],
  partials: [Partials.GUILD_MEMBER, Partials.USER],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} is alive!`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
  if (
    msg.author.id === "1169644794788716685" ||
    msg.author.id === "282859044593598464"
  )
    return;

  const destinyChannel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get("1169671299459731536");
  if (msg.channelId === "1169011873031659590") {
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(await webhook.fetchMessage(msg.id));
    destinyChannel.send(
      `New message in <#${msg.channelId}>, <@&1169442693756223508>`
    );
  }
});

client.setMaxListeners(0);

client.login(config.bot.token);
// .login(config.bot.token)
// .then(() => {
//   console.log(`${client.user.username} is active`);
// })
// .catch((err) => {
//   console.error(err);
// });
```

> I know it's messy, but I want to achieve my goal and then clean it up.

How can I accomplish what I want using the [WebhookClient](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/WebhookClient?scrollTo=fetchMessage) (maybe)?

Someone would help me, please? Or tell me if it's impossible.